# GetAsTargetRange() for TextSelection results in Object reference not set

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I automating text higlighting in Microsoft Word.,

```
TextSelection[] textSelections = document.FindAllString(this.textBox1.Text, true, true);
foreach(TextSelection selection in textSelections)
{
   selection.GetAsTargetRange().CharacterFormat.HighlightColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

The above results in:

> Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Post code where variables are initialized

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint?

Comment: show some other parts of how do you proceed.

Comment: Yeah, I find that the GetAsTargetRange() get wrong without a object reference return, It is still none.  I will put other information.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason might be this.textBox1.Text should not be empty or some character not existed in your document. That means you should add some text to set up your object as the target range.

Comment: But I already set it text  let's say:  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "some character";
        }

Comment: See that is the problem. You should set its text from the beginning.

Comment: Use Properties or  "set" text,  only in that way, you can go through it whenever you just begin or change its text.

Comment: Yep, I see where I am going wrong. I need GetAsTargetRange() to return object everytime, not just when the "text" changed.  I forget to initialize its text.  Many Thanks for helping me out.